# CMS для Django (в частности, для построения типовых магазинов)

Tags: веб-программирование, cms, django

Почитал [тут](http://softwaremaniacs.org/forum/django/28707/), что народ пишет про Django CMS 2 и думаю, стоит ли париться? Не проще ли самому собрать все аппы, которые обычно нужны (допилив до нужного вида), а  для админки расковырять `django-admin-tools`?

В частности, постоянно просят сделать что-нибудь быстренькое, типовое. И что-то, когда сам делаю быстренько (в основном, с админкой), не выходит.

Вот по CMS для магазинов я так понял, [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) - это основной проект? Кто пользовался, поделитесь мнением. =)

**UPD**
Есть light-аналог Satchmo, [LFS](http://www.getlfs.com/) - идеология в том, чтобы можно было быстро построить магазин из коробки. В Satchmo же суть в полной настраиваемости , но пишут что админка вызывает много вопросов.

Не знаю как быть. С одной стороны не хочется усложнять. С другой стороны полезно разобраться сразу с полнофункциональным проектом. Чувствую что придется с обоими разбираться=)

P.S. Ну, для всяких социалок, это уж без вариантов, юзал [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу скажу, никогда не пользовался готовыми CMS для Джанго.

Дело в том, что создание CMS для Джанго противоречит самой сути Джанго! Основная идея — CMS, какой бы хорошей она ни была, не сможет дать нужной гибкости, зато даст много ненужного мусора. Джанго для того и существует, чтобы максимально упростить разработку *данного конкретного* веб-приложения для *данной конкретной* ситуации.

Если же Вы собираетесь делать не шедевр (и даже не полушедевр), а какую-то быструю «отписку» за несерьёзную цену, то Джанго тут не при чём. Возьмите готовую CMS.

Comment: да,полностью согласен про гибкость. поэтому всякими джумлами не пользовался серьезно никогда=) не,отписку делать тоже не делаю и не дают делать-все как войдут во вкус,как раздухоряться- это нам тоже надо,и это и то и сё...вобще коенчно вопрос был больше про набор аппов для быстрой реализации магазинов с базовым функционалом. 
ЗЫ хотя вот ща другу помогаю. задача стандартная.больше траблов с версткой. и ручками я сделаю все быстрее и надежнее, но интересно затестить готовое решение какое-нибудь.

Answer (score 1):

Кроме Satchmo есть ещё [LFS](http://www.getlfs.com/), правда ни тем, ни другим пока не пользовался.

Answer (score 0):

[Oscar](http://oscarcommerce.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Не лезьте вы в эти Satchmo и LFS. Для магазина используйте OpenCart, меньше гемороя будет, а то, что PHP - ну так не для каждой же задачи Django допиливать.

Comment: Не знаю, не знаю.... вопрос все-таки про Django был. На php я бы и от джумлы не отказался. Да, и я поковырял Satchmo - отличный проект. Все базовые возможности реализованы, проблем с установкой и настройкой не возникло (под windows, я молчу уже про линукс). В чем преимущество LFS я так и не понял. =) Куда проще-то? )

Comment: Для Django на сегодня нет ни одного нормального решения для магазинов. Virtuemart для Joomla очень громоздок и неповоротлив (по крайней мере, был года полтора назад). А уж когда начнутся проблемы с допиливанием Satchmo, легче будет переписать под тот же OpenCart и воспользоваться плагинами сообщества, которое, кстати, гораздо более обширно и отзывчиво. Я не говорю против Django, это лучший фрэймворк, с каким я когда-либо работал. Просто, когда вам нужно будет по-быстрому прикрутить модуль для робокассы или оплаты из киви кошелька, вы сто раз пожалеете о выборе Satchmo.